# How to find the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2+y^2}\frac{e^z}{1-z}dzdxdy$?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2+y^2}\frac{e^z}{1-z}dzdxdy$$

This problem was asked in a test.

I tried to expand $\frac1{1-z}$ and $e^z$,

$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

but i don't know what to do next.

Comment: The innermost integral fails to converge for all $x,y$ between 0 and 1.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you!I think you are right!

Answer (score 1):

First, we use the cauchy product for series. Note that, $$e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{z^{n}}{n!}}\qquad\qquad \dfrac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z^{n}}$$

So, $$\dfrac{e^z}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{ \dfrac{z^{k}}{k!}z^{n-k} }}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{ \dfrac{z^{n}}{k!} }}=1+2z+\frac{5}{2}z^{2}+\frac{8}{3}z^{3}+\frac{65}{24}z^{4}+\ldots$$

Now, you just have to integrate this series.

Comment: The geometric series only converges for $|z|<1$.